# Is it possible to get minlength value from formcontrol?

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, components, frontend

So i have my form validation.
And my question is can i get for example a minlength value which i passed at creating formControl?

I havent found any information.

This is my dumb component and i want to get minlength value to pass to information. Now i need to pass it via @Input().

```
title: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(20)]]
```

.

```
<div class="validation-window">
  <p *ngIf="errors.required">
    {{field}} required
  </p>
  <p *ngIf="formControl.hasError('minlength')">
      {{field}} at least {{minLegth}} characters
  </p>
  <p *ngIf="formControl.hasError('maxlength')">
      {{field}} at least {{maxLength}} characters
  </p>
</div>
```

I want to replace {{maxLength}} with something like formControl.validators.minlength.value;

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can access the number of the length, both in maxlength and minlength. You can find it inside the `error` object, where it lies under `.maxlength.requiredLength` && `minlength.requiredLength`. There is also a field with `actualLength`, but you don't seem to need it, but if you sometimes do! :)

```html
<p *ngIf="formControl.hasError('maxlength')">
  {{field}} at max {{formControl.errors.maxlength.requiredLength}} characters
</p>

<p *ngIf="formControl.hasError('minlength')">
  {{field}} at least {{formControl.errors.minlength.requiredLength}} characters
</p>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d9ktws?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: and what if I want to display that value in the hint like 10/100? the only way is to wait until the error happened?

Comment: Alternatively  {{formControl.errors?.['minlength'].requiredLength}} will work as well, if you want to skip the possibly null error

Comment: Angular 16x -> {{formControl.get('fieldName')?.errors?.['minlength'].requiredLength}}