# How can I get validator function parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  value: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]]
});
```

I want to get the **4** from **Validators.minLength(4)**.

How can I get this?

Comment: where in your code do want to get that value? If it's in the html to display a message you can look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975103/is-it-possible-to-get-minlength-value-from-formcontrol

Comment: No, I want to get this value before the validation error. @Juan

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @adiga to not populate the array if validation is in limit.

Comment: Why not use a constant instead of directly passing 4?

Comment: @caTS I cant do that because I have created a new field accessor, and I want to use this data inside of it.

Comment: can you create small example of your scenario on stackblitz and update your question? that would make it a lot easier to provide any possible solutions to your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this stackblitz URL for your above issue I've given a details answer.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gjcu4t?file=src/app/app.component.html

TypeScript

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

    formDummy: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
     val: [
     '',
     Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]),
    ],
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.formDummy.get('val').patchValue('12');
     console.log(this.formDummy.controls['val'].errors.minlength);
    
      console.log('ActualLength ',
      this.formDummy.controls['val'].errors.minlength.actualLength);
     
      console.log('requiredLength ',
      this.formDummy.controls['val'].errors.minlength.requiredLength
  );
 }
}
```

HTML Code for show errors

```
 <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
  <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>

<form [formGroup]="formDummy">
  <input type="text" formControlName="val" placeholder="Enter number here" />
  <br />

  Value => {{ formDummy.get('val')?.value }}
  <br />
  RequireLength {{ formDummy.get('val')?.errors.minlength.requiredLength }}
  <br />
  ActualLength {{ formDummy.get('val')?.errors.minlength.actualLength }}
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Disclamer:** I'm not prety sure if this can help you

As you can get the "validator" and a validator is a function, you can "check" agains an "on-fly" formControl

```
const error=this.form.get('value').validator(
    new FormControl('1')
)
if (error && error.minlength)
   console.log(error.minlength.requiredLength)
```